# Fourier transform not decaying to $0$

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

If $f \in L^1$ then the Fourier transform $\hat{f}(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) e^{ikx}dx$ converges and $|\hat{f}(k)| \to 0$ as $|k| \to \infty$ by Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

I'm looking for examples where the Fourier integral is convergent but (1) limit of the the transform is not $0$ and (2) limit of the transform does not exist if possible.

Obviously requires that the integral is convergent conditionally.

Comment: Think about the Plancherel theorem...